# Can I use Health Kit in my app if my app is not published on app store

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit

I have an application that is not published on Apple App Store but it can be installed via a URL.
Now I want to integrate Apple Health Kit into this app. Are there any restrictions from Apple for doing this considering my app is not published in App Store.

Comment: Not publishing through the App Store is already not supported by Apple, but since you are not going through App Review, Apple's guidelines don't apply.  Your app either works or it doesn't. Your only challenge is getting users who are installing a non-reviewed, non-App Store app to give your app Health data access

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, this app is only for a specific set of users, so that is not a challenge for us. Thanks for the clarification.